# Formatting a string to 2 decimal places?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a number that looks like this:

`'0000040000'`

How can I turn it into a string that looks like this:

`400.00`

This should work on numbers like this as well :

`1234540067` -> `12345400.67`

Comment: Does it always have 10 digits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it's fair to say you have a string that you would like to format as a number.

If you want to "learn" how to do this, I suggest looking up the `convert`, `cast` and `format` functions for SQL Server and gain some extra knowledge.

I've elected to first convert to a numeric type, divide by 100 and format the output.
This saves the need to trim leading zero's.

`select format(convert(numeric(18,2), '0000040001') / 100, '0.00'))`

Answer (score 2):

Following SQL expression will first change string to decimal and then convert it back to a string in a required format:

`SELECT FORMAT(CAST ('0000040000' AS DECIMAL(12,2))/100,'#.00')`

Comment: Don't use FORMAT. It can be up to 40 times slower than other options.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is more of mathematical one.
To get the last 2 numbers after decimals, get the remainder of the number by dividing it by 100.
To get the digits, leaving the last 2 digits, divide the number by 100 again.

`select convert(varchar,1234540067/100)+'.'+ convert(varchar,1234540067% 100);`

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low-quality. Your answer is likely to be deleted if you don't edit it so as to add an explanation

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select convert(varchar(10), convert(decimal(10, 2), try_convert(int, '0000040000') / 100.0))
```

Why do you want the value as a string?  Does a decimal work for your purposes?

Another method is:

```
select ltrim(str(try_convert(int, '0000040000') / 100.0, 10, 2))
```

Or using just string manipulations:

```
select replace(ltrim(replace(stuff('0000040000', 9, 0, '.'), '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
```

This would be more elegant if `ltrim()` in SQL Server accepted the character to trim (as most other databases allow).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a some possible solutions:

```
DECLARE @x CHAR(10)='0000040000'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),CONVERT(NUMERIC(10),@x)/100))
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),STUFF(@x,9,0,'.')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this:

```
SELECT ROUND('0000040004', 2, 1)/100;
```

Tested this with SQL Server 2017. It does not care about the fact that the number is a string, it does math on it just fine. Result of the above is 400.04